# Multiple choice menu in Linux Script

Tags: linux, bash, scripting

I made a script with which I get a list of files from 5 servers.
Output of the script is something like this:

```
--------------------------------------------------------
   Server1|
--------------------------------------------------------
Jun   | 25    | 14:40 | ./DEPE_ES36250145.22.DEL.Z    
Jun   | 26    | 08:37 | ./DEPE_ES35470064.22.DEL.Z    
Jun   | 26    | 09:25 | ./FRESCHI_ORDERS_201906260906.DEL.Z
Jun   | 26    | 13:05 | ./0003625_ORDERS_20190626_130521.DEL.Z
```

My desire is to to launch one of the two scripts that I wrote.

After getting the list of files I want to select the file name (maybe with the mouse so that I can paste it), wish to be prompted to copy/digit the file name, 
then prompted (with options) to select the server from which to recover the file.

Based on this, I wrote this menu script.

```
# Copia File Ordini in Locale
# Bash Menu Script
PS1='Cosa vuoi recuperare? '
options=("Ordini" "Quadrature" "Annulla")
select opt in "${options[@]}"
do
    case $opt in
        "Option 1")
            $ordini='./getFileOrd.sh'
            eval $ordini
            ;;
        "Option 2")
            $quad='./getFileOrdQ.sh'
            eval $quad
            ;;
        "Annulla")
            break
            ;;
    esac
done

read -p "Quale file vuoi recuperare? (Copia e incolla il nome del file compresa l'estensione) " file

PS2="Da quale server vuoi copiare" $file "? "
options=("Server1" "Server2" "Server3" "Server4" "Server5" "Annulla")
select opt in "${options[@]}"
do
    case $opt in
        "Option 1")
            sftp -q User1@Server1:/work/app/User1/riordino_sb/historical/output/"$file"
            ;;
        "Option 2")
            sftp -q User1@Server2:/work/app/User1/riordino_sb/historical/output/"$file"
            ;;
        "Option 3")
            sftp -q User1@Server3:/work/app/User1/riordino_sb/historical/output/"$file"
            ;;
        "Option 4")
            sftp -q User1@Server4:/work/app/User1/riordino_sb/historical/output/"$file"
            ;;
        "Option 5")
            sftp -q User1@Server5:/work/app/User1/riordino_sb/historical/output/"$file"
            ;;
        "Annulla")
            break
            ;;
        *) echo "Scegli una delle opzioni";;
    esac
done
```

At the end of the script, selected file is copied in the home directory of the user. Menus work fine. My problem is that `./getFileOrd.sh` doesn't start and probably also the second part of the script.

Comment: To begin with, you have a '$' sign on the left hand side (LHS) of assignments (`$ordini=`). The '$' can only ever occur in RHS references.

Comment: Should it not be "file='./getFileOrd.sh'` and `file='./getFileOrdQ.sh'`?

Comment: @FrancescoCicciuzz: You forgot to describe where you have the problem with your script.

Comment: I think you want to set PS3: `PS3='Cosa vuoi recuperare? '`.

Comment: ./getFileOrd.sh doesn't start, therefore I can't select file to download.

Comment: Also the secondo part of the script wont start. Maybe for the same problem of not being able to run another script like ./getFileOrd.sh

Comment: How do you execute the script? I don't see the `#!` line, so perhaps it is being executed with /bin/sh? You use arrays so you need to specify bash.

Comment: In the first 'select'-statement, you must list the possibilities that the options-array gives. So 'Ordini' instead of "Option 1", etc.

Comment: Please, add this line after all your options: `echo "opt = $opt"`.

Comment: @glennjackman script is lanched with ./optionScript.sh

Comment: Why are you using `eval`? You should just execute the "Ord" script as a program.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is to get you on your way:

```
#!/bin/bash

# Copia File Ordini in Locale
# Bash Menu Script
PS3='Cosa vuoi recuperare? '
options=("Ordini" "Quadrature" "Annulla")
declare scr

select opt in "${options[@]}"
do
    case $opt in
        "Ordini")
            scr='./getFileOrd.sh'
            break
            ;;
        "Quadrature")
            scr='./getFileOrdQ.sh'
            break
            ;;
        "Annulla")
            break
            ;;
    esac
done

echo "script = $scr"
[ ! -z $scr ] && eval "$scr"

# where is $file set???  <--- ???

PS3="Da quale server vuoi copiare ${file}?"
options=("Server1" "Server2" "Server3" "Server4" "Server5" "Annulla")
select opt in "${options[@]}"
do
    case $opt in
        "Server1")
            sftp -q User1@Server1:/work/app/User1/riordino_sb/historical/output/"$file"
            break
            ;;
        "Server2")
            sftp -q User1@Server2:/work/app/User1/riordino_sb/historical/output/"$file"
            break
            ;;
        "Server3")
            sftp -q User1@Server3:/work/app/User1/riordino_sb/historical/output/"$file"
            break
            ;;
        "Server4")
            sftp -q User1@Server4:/work/app/User1/riordino_sb/historical/output/"$file"
            break
            ;;
        "Server5")
            sftp -q User1@Server5:/work/app/User1/riordino_sb/historical/output/"$file"
            break
            ;;
        "Annulla")
            break
            ;;
        *) echo "Scegli una delle opzioni";;
    esac
done
```

Comment: ~]$ ./optionScript.sh 
1) Ordini                                                                                                                                                                                 
2) Quadrature 
3) Annulla
Cosa vuoi recuperare? 2
opt = Quadrature
./optionScript.sh: line 19: =./getFileOrdQ.sh: No such file or directory

Comment: My mistake. I copied your own erroneous code, with the '$" in front of "ordini" and "quad". I corrected that, please take note.

Comment: Glad for you. I think now you can get the second part done on your own.

Comment: Btw., also note that there is a `break` statement after each option, not just only  'Annulla'! I think you want to add these to each option in the second part as well.

Comment: There is slightly different way of doing this: you might seta variable 'file' in each option substatement, and then eval that outside the select statement.

Comment: I've modified my answer to include your second fragment.  It is not clear however where "$file" comes from. You must correct this.  Also, my modifications try to follow your original script, but there are a few more optimal and elegant ways to achieve what you are trying to do.

Comment: I managed to make it my self, but it's similar to yours. Anyway, you deserve the right answer!

Answer (score 0):

Alternative:

```
#!/bin/bash

# Copia File Ordini in Locale
# Bash Menu Script
PS3='Cosa vuoi recuperare? '
options=("Ordini" "Quadrature" "Annulla")
declare file

select opt in "${options[@]}"
do
    case $opt in
        "Ordini")
            file='./getFileOrd.sh'
            break
            ;;
        "Quadrature")
            file='./getFileOrdQ.sh'
            break
            ;;
        "Annulla")
            break
            ;;
    esac
done

echo "file = $file"
[ ! -z $file ] && eval "$file"
```

Comment: So, first part of the batch works well. Script starts and gets the files.
After I'm prompted to enter a file and i just copy and paste with mouse. This works as well.
But I'm not prompted with the second PS.
Actually returns to the first one.

Comment: Change it to PS3.